# Auto-generate DBML from entities?

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

Is there a way to generate the DBML file from entity classes instead from database tables? This would be very useful for prototyping, where one just creates a logical model and lets the auto-generated tool create the DBML file. With DBML file, one can use SqlMetal to generate Linq to SQL classes and be done with it. So, to prototype rapidly, one would:

1.Define models

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    // etc
}
```

2.Run the tool (with chosen entities)

3.Get the auto-generated DBML file

4.Run the [SqlMetal tool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386987.aspx) or [Damiens t4 scripts](http://damieng.com/blog/2009/01/19/linq-to-sql-templates-updated-now-on-codeplex) to create Linq to SQL classes

5.Code against auto-generated data-context and auto-generated database (using DataContext.CreateDatabase() to create the intial DB, for instance). Some sort of DB migration would be even nicer.

Or am I weird for wanting to generate DB from objects instead of objects from DB? :)

Comment: Nowdays, an interesting alternative to that is by using FluentNHibernate with its auto-mapping capabilities, along with NHibernate.Linq. That way, it is very straightforward to come up with a database model and it is very easy to customize the auto-mapping as well. I hope that helps others as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doesn't exist. Currently the only method of generate a DBML for Linq to SQL is from a sql database source.

This might someday exist for the Entity Framework but current not there either.

Answer (score 0):

I actually do it in a slightly different fashion:

1. Define an **XML** model of my data structures
2. Use XSLT to generate stored procedure for create, read, upsert, etc.
3. Use the stored procedures to create the database
4. Work with Linq→SQL in a typical fashion, importing the stored procedures (I don't import the model because Linq→SQL doesn't know how to work with the groovy '2008 features)
5. Work with the model